SMTP dummy email address
Help please when i tried to enter a dummy email it's still continues in this code and heading to my other webpage with ?success=inserted, i already prevent any dummy email from entering but when they just add random letters and numbers and add "@gmail.com" it's still proceeds so what i want is that if the SMTP detects that it was unable to send the email because of invalid email address it will shows an error
Please help me i'm a graduating student trying to pass my Capstone Project
try {
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            // Check if the error indicates invalid or non-existent email
            if (strpos($mail->ErrorInfo, '550 5.1.1') !== false) {
                // Invalid or non-existent email address error
                if ($_SESSION['role'] === 'Head IT') {
                    // Redirect Head IT to headit_error.php
                    header("Location: index0.php?error=invalid_email");
                } else {
                    // Redirect IT personnel to itpersonnel_error.php
                    header("Location: index1.php?error=invalid_email");
                }
                exit();
            } else {
                // Other mailer errors
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            // Email sent successfully
            if ($_SESSION['role'] === 'Head IT') {
                header("Location: index0.php?success=inserted");
                exit();
            } else {
                header("Location: index1.php?success=inserted");
                exit();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }


A non-existent address won't necessarily cause it to fail to send. It might cause it to fail to be delivered, but that's different, and not something your code can detect (unless it watches a mailbox for bounce messages, perhaps)

Not related to your problem probably, but I usually strongly discourage using try blocks during development unless you actually do something relevant in your catch, which you aren’t.

To your problem, back a couple of decades ago you used send an email to xyz@example.com, and if that MTA didn’t know who xyz was it would throw an error. Then the spammers came out and did dictionary attacks, trying alice, bob, etc., and they recorded all the non-failures as “success”. This lead to some MTAs to stop responding negatively to unknown users, and instead either “black hole” the message, or return a bounce to the sender (if they were polite). The tl;dr is that determining whether an address exists at a specific mail service is not usually a programming problem.

...which is why a lot of sites now do email verification where they send an email to an address the user entered, which contains a unique URL. And they don't count the email address as valid until the user has opened that mail and clicked on the link (the link of course leads back to the application, which can then detect that the specific link was clicked, and it stored the association between that URL and the email address, so it now knows that the email address definitely exists)
